# Echart vs 5: I cannot get Sliders in three containers combined to work as one

Tags: echarts

I have succeeded in making three charts (containers) above each other in ECHARTS v5 and all works fine. However, I need all three sliders to work as one. Meaning that if I change one slider the other two must do exactly the same so the x-Axis data remains the same to make comparison easier.

Is this possible and if yes how? <Remark: Has been answered by 'A mere dev' and the solution is in the code below >.
Now need to add an additional candle chart in myChart1 part to show Heikin Ashi candles with on off toggle just like the lines in myChart1.
< made a new question if this: [Link to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71818784/echarts-vs-5-how-can-i-add-an-additional-candle-chart-for-heikin-ashi-candles-i)>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body style="height: 100%; margin: 0">
        <div id="container1" style="height: 34%"></div>
                <div id="container2" style="height: 33%"></div>
                <div id="container3" style="height: 33%"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="echarts.min_All.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//===========================================================================================================
var dom1 = document.getElementById("container1");
var myChart1 = echarts.init(dom1);
var app = {};

var option1;
const upColor = '#00da3c'; 
const upBorderColor = '#008F28';
const downColor = '#ec0000';
const downBorderColor = '#8A0000';
// Each item: open，close，lowest，highest
const data0 = splitData([
  ['2013/1/24', 2320.26, 2320.26, 2287.3, 2362.94],
  ['2013/1/25', 2300, 2291.3, 2288.26, 2308.38],
  ['2013/1/28', 2295.35, 2346.5, 2295.35, 2346.92],
  ['2013/1/29', 2347.22, 2358.98, 2337.35, 2363.8],
  ['2013/1/30', 2360.75, 2382.48, 2347.89, 2383.76],
  ['2013/1/31', 2383.43, 2385.42, 2371.23, 2391.82],
  ['2013/2/1', 2377.41, 2419.02, 2369.57, 2421.15],
  ['2013/2/4', 2425.92, 2428.15, 2417.58, 2440.38],
  ['2013/2/5', 2411, 2433.13, 2403.3, 2437.42],
  ['2013/2/6', 2432.68, 2434.48, 2427.7, 2441.73],
  ['2013/2/7', 2430.69, 2418.53, 2394.22, 2433.89],
  ['2013/2/8', 2416.62, 2432.4, 2414.4, 2443.03],
  ['2013/2/18', 2441.91, 2421.56, 2415.43, 2444.8],
  ['2013/2/19', 2420.26, 2382.91, 2373.53, 2427.07],
  ['2013/2/20', 2383.49, 2397.18, 2370.61, 2397.94],
  ['2013/2/21', 2378.82, 2325.95, 2309.17, 2378.82],
  ['2013/2/22', 2322.94, 2314.16, 2308.76, 2330.88],
  ['2013/2/25', 2320.62, 2325.82, 2315.01, 2338.78],
  ['2013/2/26', 2313.74, 2293.34, 2289.89, 2340.71],
  ['2013/2/27', 2297.77, 2313.22, 2292.03, 2324.63],
  ['2013/2/28', 2322.32, 2365.59, 2308.92, 2366.16],
  ['2013/3/1', 2364.54, 2359.51, 2330.86, 2369.65],
  ['2013/3/4', 2332.08, 2273.4, 2259.25, 2333.54],
  ['2013/3/5', 2274.81, 2326.31, 2270.1, 2328.14],
  ['2013/3/6', 2333.61, 2347.18, 2321.6, 2351.44],
  ['2013/3/7', 2340.44, 2324.29, 2304.27, 2352.02],
  ['2013/3/8', 2326.42, 2318.61, 2314.59, 2333.67],
  ['2013/3/11', 2314.68, 2310.59, 2296.58, 2320.96],
  ['2013/3/12', 2309.16, 2286.6, 2264.83, 2333.29],
  ['2013/3/13', 2282.17, 2263.97, 2253.25, 2286.33],
  ['2013/3/14', 2255.77, 2270.28, 2253.31, 2276.22],
  ['2013/3/15', 2269.31, 2278.4, 2250, 2312.08],
  ['2013/3/18', 2267.29, 2240.02, 2239.21, 2276.05],
  ['2013/3/19', 2244.26, 2257.43, 2232.02, 2261.31],
  ['2013/3/20', 2257.74, 2317.37, 2257.42, 2317.86],
  ['2013/3/21', 2318.21, 2324.24, 2311.6, 2330.81],
  ['2013/3/22', 2321.4, 2328.28, 2314.97, 2332],
  ['2013/3/25', 2334.74, 2326.72, 2319.91, 2344.89],
  ['2013/3/26', 2318.58, 2297.67, 2281.12, 2319.99],
  ['2013/3/27', 2299.38, 2301.26, 2289, 2323.48],
  ['2013/3/28', 2273.55, 2236.3, 2232.91, 2273.55],
  ['2013/3/29', 2238.49, 2236.62, 2228.81, 2246.87],
  ['2013/4/1', 2229.46, 2234.4, 2227.31, 2243.95],
  ['2013/4/2', 2234.9, 2227.74, 2220.44, 2253.42],
  ['2013/4/3', 2232.69, 2225.29, 2217.25, 2241.34],
  ['2013/4/8', 2196.24, 2211.59, 2180.67, 2212.59],
  ['2013/4/9', 2215.47, 2225.77, 2215.47, 2234.73],
  ['2013/4/10', 2224.93, 2226.13, 2212.56, 2233.04],
  ['2013/4/11', 2236.98, 2219.55, 2217.26, 2242.48],
  ['2013/4/12', 2218.09, 2206.78, 2204.44, 2226.26],
  ['2013/4/15', 2199.91, 2181.94, 2177.39, 2204.99],
  ['2013/4/16', 2169.63, 2194.85, 2165.78, 2196.43],
  ['2013/4/17', 2195.03, 2193.8, 2178.47, 2197.51],
  ['2013/4/18', 2181.82, 2197.6, 2175.44, 2206.03],
  ['2013/4/19', 2201.12, 2244.64, 2200.58, 2250.11],
  ['2013/4/22', 2236.4, 2242.17, 2232.26, 2245.12],
  ['2013/4/23', 2242.62, 2184.54, 2182.81, 2242.62],
  ['2013/4/24', 2187.35, 2218.32, 2184.11, 2226.12],
  ['2013/4/25', 2213.19, 2199.31, 2191.85, 2224.63],
  ['2013/4/26', 2203.89, 2177.91, 2173.86, 2210.58],
  ['2013/5/2', 2170.78, 2174.12, 2161.14, 2179.65],
  ['2013/5/3', 2179.05, 2205.5, 2179.05, 2222.81],
  ['2013/5/6', 2212.5, 2231.17, 2212.5, 2236.07],
  ['2013/5/7', 2227.86, 2235.57, 2219.44, 2240.26],
  ['2013/5/8', 2242.39, 2246.3, 2235.42, 2255.21],
  ['2013/5/9', 2246.96, 2232.97, 2221.38, 2247.86],
  ['2013/5/10', 2228.82, 2246.83, 2225.81, 2247.67],
  ['2013/5/13', 2247.68, 2241.92, 2231.36, 2250.85],
  ['2013/5/14', 2238.9, 2217.01, 2205.87, 2239.93],
  ['2013/5/15', 2217.09, 2224.8, 2213.58, 2225.19],
  ['2013/5/16', 2221.34, 2251.81, 2210.77, 2252.87],
  ['2013/5/17', 2249.81, 2282.87, 2248.41, 2288.09],
  ['2013/5/20', 2286.33, 2299.99, 2281.9, 2309.39],
  ['2013/5/21', 2297.11, 2305.11, 2290.12, 2305.3],
  ['2013/5/22', 2303.75, 2302.4, 2292.43, 2314.18],
  ['2013/5/23', 2293.81, 2275.67, 2274.1, 2304.95],
  ['2013/5/24', 2281.45, 2288.53, 2270.25, 2292.59],
  ['2013/5/27', 2286.66, 2293.08, 2283.94, 2301.7],
  ['2013/5/28', 2293.4, 2321.32, 2281.47, 2322.1],
  ['2013/5/29', 2323.54, 2324.02, 2321.17, 2334.33],
  ['2013/5/30', 2316.25, 2317.75, 2310.49, 2325.72],
  ['2013/5/31', 2320.74, 2300.59, 2299.37, 2325.53],
  ['2013/6/3', 2300.21, 2299.25, 2294.11, 2313.43],
  ['2013/6/4', 2297.1, 2272.42, 2264.76, 2297.1],
  ['2013/6/5', 2270.71, 2270.93, 2260.87, 2276.86],
  ['2013/6/6', 2264.43, 2242.11, 2240.07, 2266.69],
  ['2013/6/7', 2242.26, 2210.9, 2205.07, 2250.63],
  ['2013/6/13', 2190.1, 2148.35, 2126.22, 2190.1],
]);
//-----------------------------------------------------
const data1 = splitData([
  ['2013/1/24', 2320.26, 2320.26, 2287.3, 2362.94],
  ['2013/1/25', 2300, 2291.3, 2288.26, 2308.38],
  ['2013/1/28', 2295.35, 2346.5, 2295.35, 2346.92],
  ['2013/1/29', 2347.22, 2358.98, 2337.35, 2363.8],
  ['2013/1/30', 2360.75, 2382.48, 2347.89, 2383.76],
  ['2013/1/31', 2383.43, 2385.42, 2371.23, 2391.82],
  ['2013/2/1', 2377.41, 2419.02, 2369.57, 2421.15],
  ['2013/2/4', 2425.92, 2428.15, 2417.58, 2440.38],
  ['2013/2/5', 2411, 2433.13, 2403.3, 2437.42],
  ['2013/2/6', 2432.68, 2434.48, 2427.7, 2441.73],
  ['2013/2/7', 2430.69, 2418.53, 2394.22, 2433.89],
  ['2013/2/8', 2416.62, 2432.4, 2414.4, 2443.03],
  ['2013/2/18', 2441.91, 2421.56, 2415.43, 2444.8],
  ['2013/2/19', 2420.26, 2382.91, 2373.53, 2427.07],
  ['2013/2/20', 2383.49, 2397.18, 2370.61, 2397.94],
  ['2013/2/21', 2378.82, 2325.95, 2309.17, 2378.82],
  ['2013/2/22', 2322.94, 2314.16, 2308.76, 2330.88],
  ['2013/2/25', 2320.62, 2325.82, 2315.01, 2338.78],
  ['2013/2/26', 2313.74, 2293.34, 2289.89, 2340.71],
  ['2013/2/27', 2297.77, 2313.22, 2292.03, 2324.63],
  ['2013/2/28', 2322.32, 2365.59, 2308.92, 2366.16],
  ['2013/3/1', 2364.54, 2359.51, 2330.86, 2369.65],
  ['2013/3/4', 2332.08, 2273.4, 2259.25, 2333.54],
  ['2013/3/5', 2274.81, 2326.31, 2270.1, 2328.14],
  ['2013/3/6', 2333.61, 2347.18, 2321.6, 2351.44],
  ['2013/3/7', 2340.44, 2324.29, 2304.27, 2352.02],
  ['2013/3/8', 2326.42, 2318.61, 2314.59, 2333.67],
  ['2013/3/11', 2314.68, 2310.59, 2296.58, 2320.96],
  ['2013/3/12', 2309.16, 2286.6, 2264.83, 2333.29],
  ['2013/3/13', 2282.17, 2263.97, 2253.25, 2286.33],
  ['2013/3/14', 2255.77, 2270.28, 2253.31, 2276.22],
  ['2013/3/15', 2269.31, 2278.4, 2250, 2312.08],
  ['2013/3/18', 2267.29, 2240.02, 2239.21, 2276.05],
  ['2013/3/19', 2244.26, 2257.43, 2232.02, 2261.31],
  ['2013/3/20', 2257.74, 2317.37, 2257.42, 2317.86],
  ['2013/3/21', 2318.21, 2324.24, 2311.6, 2330.81],
  ['2013/3/22', 2321.4, 2328.28, 2314.97, 2332],
  ['2013/3/25', 2334.74, 2326.72, 2319.91, 2344.89],
  ['2013/3/26', 2318.58, 2297.67, 2281.12, 2319.99],
  ['2013/3/27', 2299.38, 2301.26, 2289, 2323.48],
  ['2013/3/28', 2273.55, 2236.3, 2232.91, 2273.55],
  ['2013/3/29', 2238.49, 2236.62, 2228.81, 2246.87],
  ['2013/4/1', 2229.46, 2234.4, 2227.31, 2243.95],
  ['2013/4/2', 2234.9, 2227.74, 2220.44, 2253.42],
  ['2013/4/3', 2232.69, 2225.29, 2217.25, 2241.34],
  ['2013/4/8', 2196.24, 2211.59, 2180.67, 2212.59],
  ['2013/4/9', 2215.47, 2225.77, 2215.47, 2234.73],
  ['2013/4/10', 2224.93, 2226.13, 2212.56, 2233.04],
  ['2013/4/11', 2236.98, 2219.55, 2217.26, 2242.48],
  ['2013/4/12', 2218.09, 2206.78, 2204.44, 2226.26],
  ['2013/4/15', 2199.91, 2181.94, 2177.39, 2204.99],
  ['2013/4/16', 2169.63, 2194.85, 2165.78, 2196.43],
  ['2013/4/17', 2195.03, 2193.8, 2178.47, 2197.51],
  ['2013/4/18', 2181.82, 2197.6, 2175.44, 2206.03],
  ['2013/4/19', 2201.12, 2244.64, 2200.58, 2250.11],
  ['2013/4/22', 2236.4, 2242.17, 2232.26, 2245.12],
  ['2013/4/23', 2242.62, 2184.54, 2182.81, 2242.62],
  ['2013/4/24', 2187.35, 2218.32, 2184.11, 2226.12],
  ['2013/4/25', 2213.19, 2199.31, 2191.85, 2224.63],
  ['2013/4/26', 2203.89, 2177.91, 2173.86, 2210.58],
  ['2013/5/2', 2170.78, 2174.12, 2161.14, 2179.65],
  ['2013/5/3', 2179.05, 2205.5, 2179.05, 2222.81],
  ['2013/5/6', 2212.5, 2231.17, 2212.5, 2236.07],
  ['2013/5/7', 2227.86, 2235.57, 2219.44, 2240.26],
  ['2013/5/8', 2242.39, 2246.3, 2235.42, 2255.21],
  ['2013/5/9', 2246.96, 2232.97, 2221.38, 2247.86],
  ['2013/5/10', 2228.82, 2246.83, 2225.81, 2247.67],
  ['2013/5/13', 2247.68, 2241.92, 2231.36, 2250.85],
  ['2013/5/14', 2238.9, 2217.01, 2205.87, 2239.93],
  ['2013/5/15', 2217.09, 2224.8, 2213.58, 2225.19],
  ['2013/5/16', 2221.34, 2251.81, 2210.77, 2252.87],
  ['2013/5/17', 2249.81, 2282.87, 2248.41, 2288.09],
  ['2013/5/20', 2286.33, 2299.99, 2281.9, 2309.39],
  ['2013/5/21', 2297.11, 2305.11, 2290.12, 2305.3],
  ['2013/5/22', 2303.75, 2302.4, 2292.43, 2314.18],
  ['2013/5/23', 2293.81, 2275.67, 2274.1, 2304.95],
  ['2013/5/24', 2281.45, 2288.53, 2270.25, 2292.59],
  ['2013/5/27', 2286.66, 2293.08, 2283.94, 2301.7],
  ['2013/5/28', 2293.4, 2321.32, 2281.47, 2322.1],
  ['2013/5/29', 2323.54, 2324.02, 2321.17, 2334.33],
  ['2013/5/30', 2316.25, 2317.75, 2310.49, 2325.72],
  ['2013/5/31', 2320.74, 2300.59, 2299.37, 2325.53],
  ['2013/6/3', 2300.21, 2299.25, 2294.11, 2313.43],
  ['2013/6/4', 2297.1, 2272.42, 2264.76, 2297.1],
  ['2013/6/5', 2270.71, 2270.93, 2260.87, 2276.86],
  ['2013/6/6', 2264.43, 2242.11, 2240.07, 2266.69],
  ['2013/6/7', 2242.26, 2210.9, 2205.07, 2250.63],
  ['2013/6/13', 2190.1, 2148.35, 2126.22, 2190.1],
]);
//-----------------------------------------------------

function splitData(rawData) {
  const categoryData = [];
  const values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
    categoryData.push(rawData[i].splice(0, 1)[0]);
    values.push(rawData[i]);
  }
  return {
    categoryData: categoryData,
    values: values
  };
}
function calculateMA(dayCount) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = data0.values.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (i < dayCount) {
      result.push('-');
      continue;
    }
    var sum = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < dayCount; j++) {
      sum += +data0.values[i - j][1];
    }
    result.push(sum / dayCount);
  }
  return result;
}
option1 = {
  title: {
    text: 'Candlesticks and Lines',
    left: 0
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      type: 'cross'
    }
    
  },
  legend: {
    data: ['Candles', 'HACandles', 'MA5', 'MA10', 'MA20', 'Indicatorline_1', 'Indicatorline_2']
  },
  grid: {
    left: '3%',
    right: '5%',
    bottom: '17%'
  },
  toolbox: {
  right: '3%',
    feature: {
     restore: { show: true },
      saveAsImage: {}
    }
  },

  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: data0.categoryData,
    boundaryGap: false,
    axisLine: { onZero: false },
    splitLine: { show: false },
    min: 'dataMin',
    max: 'dataMax'
  },
  
  yAxis: {
    scale: true,
    splitArea: {
      show: true
    }
  },
  dataZoom: [
    {
      type: 'inside',
      start: 50,
      end: 100,
    },
    {
      show: true,
      type: 'slider',
      top: '8%',
      start: 50,
      end: 100,
      height: 20,
      handleSize: '100%'
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Candles',
      type: 'candlestick',
      data: data0.values,
      itemStyle: {
        color: upColor,
        color0: downColor,
        borderColor: upBorderColor,
        borderColor0: downBorderColor
      },
      //-------------------------------------------
      name: 'HACandles',
      type: 'candlestick',
      data: data1.values,
      itemStyle: {
        color: upColor,
        color0: downColor,
        borderColor: upBorderColor,
        borderColor0: downBorderColor
      },
      //----------------------------------------
      markPoint: {
        label: {
          formatter: function (param) {
            return param != null ? Math.round(param.value) + '' : '';
          }
        },
        data: [
          {
            name: 'Mark1',
            coord: ['2013/5/31', 2230],
            value: 12,
            itemStyle: {
              color: 'rgb(0,204,102)'
            }
          },
          {
            name: 'Mark2',
            coord: ['2013/6/4', 2250],
            value: 12,
            itemStyle: {
              color: 'rgb(41,60,85)'
            }
          },
        ],
        tooltip: {
          formatter: function (param) {
            return param.name + '<br>' + (param.data.coord || '');
          }
        }
      },
      //----------------------------------------------------
      markLine: {
        symbol: ['none', 'none'],
        data: [
            //-------------------------------------
          [
            {
              name: 'Position_01',
              type: 'min', 
              coord: ['2013/5/31', 2230],
              symbol: 'circle',
              symbolSize: 10,
              itemStyle: {
              color: 'rgb(0,204,102)'
                },      
              label: {
                show: false
              },
              emphasis: {
                label: {
                  show: false
                }
              }
            },
            {
              type: 'max',
              coord: ['2013/6/4', 2250],
              symbol: 'circle',
              symbolSize: 10,
              label: {
                show: false
              },
              emphasis: {
                label: {
                  show: false
                }
              },
            },
          ],
          //-------------------------------------
          [
            {
              name: 'Position_02', //from lowest to highest
              type: 'min', 
              coord: ['2013/5/6', 2230],
              symbol: 'circle',
              symbolSize: 10,
               itemStyle: {
              color: 'rgb(255,0,0)'
                },  
              label: {
                show: true
              },
              emphasis: {
                label: {
                  show: true
                }
              }
            },
            {
              type: 'max',
              coord: ['2013/5/14', 2200],
              symbol: 'circle',
              symbolSize: 10,
              label: {
                show: true
              },
              emphasis: {
                label: {
                  show: true
                }
              },
            },
          ],
          //--------------------------------------
        ]
      }
    },
    // Lines
    {
      name: 'MA5',
      type: 'line',
      data: calculateMA(5),
      smooth: true,
      lineStyle: {
        opacity: 0.5
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'MA10',
      type: 'line',
      data: calculateMA(10),
      smooth: true,
      lineStyle: {
        opacity: 0.5
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'MA20',
      type: 'line',
      data: calculateMA(20),
      smooth: true,
      lineStyle: {
        opacity: 0.5
      }
    },
      {
      name: 'Indicatorline_1',
      type: 'line',
          itemStyle: {
              color: 'rgb(255,0,0)'
                },  
      data: [2190.1, 2148.35, 2126.22, 2190.1, 2242.26, 2210.9, 2205.07, 2250.63, 2264.43, 2242.11, 2240.07, 2266.69,2190.1, 2148.35],
      smooth: true,
      lineStyle: {
        opacity: 0.5
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Indicatorline_2',
      type: 'line',
      itemStyle: {
              color: 'rgb(0,128,255)'
                },      
      data:  [2320.26, 2300.92, 2347.224,2360.75, 2383.43, 2377.41, 2425.92,2320.26, 2300.92, 2347.224, 2360.75, 2383.43, 2377.41, 2425.92],
      smooth: true,
      lineStyle: {
        opacity: 0.5
      }
    }
  ]
};

if (option1 && typeof option1 === 'object') {
    myChart1.setOption(option1);
}
//===========================================================================================================
var dom2 = document.getElementById("container2");
var myChart2 = echarts.init(dom2);
var app = {};
var option2;


option2 = {
  title: {
    text: 'Lines Graph',
    left: 0
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
        axisPointer: {
      type: 'cross',
      crossStyle: {
        color: '#999'
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
    data: ['Line_1', 'Line_2', 'Line_3', 'Line_4', 'Line_5']
  },
  grid: {
    left: '1%',
    right: '5%',
    bottom: '15%',
    containLabel: true
  },
  toolbox: {
   right: '3%',
    feature: {
     restore: { show: true },
      saveAsImage: {}
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: false,
    data: data0.categoryData,
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
  },
  //------
    dataZoom: [
    {
      type: 'inside',
      start: 50,
      end: 100
    },

    {
      show: true,
      type: 'slider',
      top: '8%',
      start: 50,
      end: 100,
        height: 20,
      handleSize: '100%'
    }
  ],
  
  //------
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Line_1',
      type: 'line',
      data: [
      120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210, 120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210, 120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210
      , 120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210, 120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210, 120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210
      , 120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210, 120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210, 120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210
      , 120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210, 120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210, 120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210
      , 120, 132, 101, 134
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Line_2',
      type: 'line',
      data: [
      220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310, 220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310, 220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310
      , 220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310, 220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310, 220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310
      , 220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310, 220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310, 220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310
      , 220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310, 220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310, 220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Line_3',
      type: 'line',
      data: [
        150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410, 150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410, 150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410
      , 150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410, 150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410, 150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410
      , 150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410, 150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410, 150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410
      , 150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410, 150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410, 150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410
      , 150, 232, 201, 154
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Line_4',
      type: 'line',
      data: [
      320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320, 320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320, 320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320
      , 320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320, 320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320, 320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320
      , 320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320, 320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320, 320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320
      , 320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320, 320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320, 320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320
      , 320, 332, 301, 334
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Line_5',
      type: 'line',
      data: [
      820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320, 820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320, 820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320
      , 820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320, 820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320, 820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320
      , 820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320, 820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320, 820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320
      , 820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320, 820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320, 820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320
      , 820, 932, 901, 934
      ]
    },
  ]
};


option2 && myChart2.setOption(option2);
//===========================================================================================================
var dom3 = document.getElementById("container3");
var myChart3 = echarts.init(dom3);
var app = {};
var option3;
option3 = {
  title: {
    text: 'Volume Bar Graph',
    left: 0
  },
   tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      type: 'cross',
      crossStyle: {
        color: '#999'
      }
    }
  },
    grid: {
    left: '1%',
    right: '5%',
    bottom: '15%',
    containLabel: true
  },
  toolbox: {
   right: '3%',
    feature: {
      dataView: { show: false, readOnly: false },
      magicType: { show: true, type: ['line', 'bar'] },
      restore: { show: true },
      saveAsImage: { show: true }
    }
  },
  legend: {
    data: ['Sell Volume', 'Buy Volume', 'Total Volume']
  },
  xAxis: [
    {
      type: 'category',
      data: data0.categoryData,
      axisPointer: {
        type: 'shadow'
      }
    }
  ],
  yAxis: [
 
    {
      type: 'value',
      name: 'Volume',
      axisLabel: {
        formatter: '{value} vol'
      }
    }
  ],
  //------
    dataZoom: [
    {
      type: 'inside',
      start: 50,
      end: 100
    },
    {
      show: true,
      type: 'slider',  
      top: '8%',
      start: 50,
      end: 100,
      height: 20,
      handleSize: '100%'
    }
  ],
  
  //------
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Sell Volume',
      type: 'bar',
      data: [
        2.0, 4.9, 7.0, 23.2, 25.6, 76.7, 135.6, 162.2, 32.6, 20.0, 6.4, 3.3, 2.0, 4.9, 7.0, 23.2, 25.6, 76.7, 135.6, 162.2, 32.6, 20.0, 6.4, 3.3, 2.0, 4.9, 7.0, 23.2, 25.6, 76.7, 135.6, 162.2, 32.6, 20.0, 6.4, 3.3
      , 2.0, 4.9, 7.0, 23.2, 25.6, 76.7, 135.6, 162.2, 32.6, 20.0, 6.4, 3.3, 2.0, 4.9, 7.0, 23.2, 25.6, 76.7, 135.6, 162.2, 32.6, 20.0, 6.4, 3.3, 2.0, 4.9, 7.0, 23.2, 25.6, 76.7, 135.6, 162.2, 32.6, 20.0, 6.4, 3.3
      , 2.0, 4.9, 7.0, 23.2, 25.6, 76.7, 135.6, 162.2, 32.6, 20.0, 6.4, 3.3, 2.0, 4.9, 7.0, 23.2,, 25.6
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Buy Volume',
      type: 'bar',
      data: [
        2.6, 5.9, 9.0, 26.4, 28.7, 70.7, 175.6, 182.2, 48.7, 18.8, 6.0, 2.3, 2.6, 5.9, 9.0, 26.4, 28.7, 70.7, 175.6, 182.2, 48.7, 18.8, 6.0, 2.3, 2.6, 5.9, 9.0, 26.4, 28.7, 70.7, 175.6, 182.2, 48.7, 18.8, 6.0, 2.3
      , 2.6, 5.9, 9.0, 26.4, 28.7, 70.7, 175.6, 182.2, 48.7, 18.8, 6.0, 2.3, 2.6, 5.9, 9.0, 26.4, 28.7, 70.7, 175.6, 182.2, 48.7, 18.8, 6.0, 2.3, 2.6, 5.9, 9.0, 26.4, 28.7, 70.7, 175.6, 182.2, 48.7, 18.8, 6.0, 2.3
      , 2.6, 5.9, 9.0, 26.4, 28.7, 70.7, 175.6, 182.2, 48.7, 18.8, 6.0, 2.3, 2.6, 5.9, 9.0, 26.4, 28.7
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Total Volume',
      type: 'line',
      data: [
      4.6, 10.8, 16.0, 49.6, 54.3, 147.4, 311.2, 344.4, 81.3, 38.8, 12.4, 5.6, 4.6, 10.8, 16.0, 49.6, 54.3, 147.4, 311.2, 344.4, 81.3, 38.8, 12.4, 5.6, 4.6, 10.8, 16.0, 49.6, 54.3, 147.4, 311.2, 344.4, 81.3, 38.8, 12.4, 5.6
      , 4.6, 10.8, 16.0, 49.6, 54.3, 147.4, 311.2, 344.4, 81.3, 38.8, 12.4, 5.6, 4.6, 10.8, 16.0, 49.6, 54.3, 147.4, 311.2, 344.4, 81.3, 38.8, 12.4, 5.6, 4.6, 10.8, 16.0, 49.6, 54.3, 147.4, 311.2, 344.4, 81.3, 38.8, 12.4, 5.6
      , 4.6, 10.8, 16.0, 49.6, 54.3, 147.4, 311.2, 344.4, 81.3, 38.8, 12.4, 5.6, 4.6, 10.8, 16.0, 49.6, 54.3
      ]
    }
  ]
};
option3 && myChart3.setOption(option3);
//===========================================================================================================
echarts.connect([myChart1, myChart2, myChart3]);
        </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `echarts.connect` to connect your charts as follow :

```js
echarts.connect([myChart1, myChart2, myChart3])
```

For this to work on your example, you'll have to remove the ids from the 3 'slider' type  `dataZoom`.

```js
dataZoom: [
  {
    type: 'inside',
    start: 50,
    end: 100
  },
  {
    show: true,
    //id: 'S3',
    type: 'slider',  
    top: '8%',
    start: 50,
    end: 100,
    height: 20,
    handleSize: '100%'
  }
],
```

Comment: Thanks for the support . It works if I place the code in the MyChart1. However if I place the code in MyChart2 and replace the MyChart names with the other charts names the page seems to go into a loop (which is logical as I invoke the first function with the functions in the other charts). Also zooming does not work. Can't seem to figure out if this can be solved. Thanks, this is already a big improvement :-).

Comment: Yes indeed, I didn't try to do it for each component but it seems logical that there is a loop. So my first solution is not really working after all, you should try the second solution (which doesn't use a workaround like the first one, but an official feature instead).

Comment: At this moment the way it works now has some benefits (user can separately use the sliders in the 2nd and 3rd chart). It would be great if I could get the mouse wheel zoom working the same way.

Comment: I modified my answer to talk about the issue you raised, and to add the mouse wheel working. But it still only works on 1 chart (because of the loop issue).

Comment: I finally found what you're looking for !

Comment: Removed the ID's on all three datazoom components. But mouse wheel zoom still only works on the first chart. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you add echarts.connect too ? I copy/pasted the code from your question and I only added the line `echarts.connect([myChart1, myChart2, myChart3])` juste before the </script>, and removed ids from the 3 datazoom and it worked (mouse wheel and slider on the 3 charts)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243476/discussion-between-a-mere-dev-and-paul-agerbeek).

Comment: I forgot to take out the dispatch action from the previous suggestions. It work perfect now. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much :-) !!!

Comment: My last challenge is now to see if I can add an additional Candle chart to already an existing candle chart in this file (used for showing Hiken Ashi Candles). Dit not get his working yet and i think this is not possible??